# Different in javascript access of element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, getelementbyid

What is the true difference between `document.getElementById('SOMEID')` and `$("[id$='SOMEID']")`
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$(..)` variant uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com), which allows you to use selectors to find what you are searching for (class, id, tag etc). The `getElementById()` is plain javascript which obviously only searches by element id.

```
$("#foo") // select elements with id foo
$(".foo") // select elements with class foo
$("foo") // select foo-tags
```

You can learn more about jQuery's support for selectors in this official [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me%3a_Using_selectors_and_events).

Comment: @user1585004 You're welcome. If you found that this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. Consider doing that for your other questions as well :-).

Comment: @user1585004 The examples in your question are also different in what elements they may match. A [`[id$="SOMEID"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) would match **any** element with an `id` **ending** in `SOMEID`, while `document.getElementById('SOMEID')` or a [`#SOMEID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) would match the **1st** element with an `id` **exactly** equal to `SOMEID`.

Comment: Let alone the return values are completely different - one returns a jQuery object while the other returns a DOM element reference.

Comment: You both are very correct, feel free to either edit my answer or add your own. I'd do it myself, but it'll just look like I'm stealing your words hehe!